# Can't change block separation in tree diagrams

Tags: draw.io

I'm using horizontal and vertical trees in draw.io. Everything's ok, except that I need the blocks closer together, but I can't find a setting for the block separation.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Arrange > Layout > Vertical tree` and set the spacing.